# how to style a tab with ActionBar Sherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, styling, android-image, android-tabs

I have the tab bar menu with ActionBar Sherlock and it works but I want to change the style, I would like to place the  text under the picture instead of in line.

This is how I add the tabs and the fragments

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

    Tab tab = actionBar.newTab()
                .setText("Resultados sorteos")
                .setTabListener(new ResultadosSorteosFragment())
                .setIcon(R.drawable.resultados_sorteos);

    actionBar.addTab(tab);

    tab = actionBar.newTab()
                .setText("Botes semana")
                .setTabListener(new BotesSemanaFragment())
                .setIcon(R.drawable.botes_semana);

    actionBar.addTab(tab);

    tab = actionBar.newTab()
                .setText("Sorteos Navidad")
                .setTabListener(new SorteosNavidadFragment())
                .setIcon(R.drawable.sorteo_navidad);

    actionBar.addTab(tab);

    tab = actionBar.newTab()
            .setText("Lector Loteria")
            .setTabListener(new LectorLoteriaFragment())
            .setIcon(R.drawable.lector_loteria);

            actionBar.addTab(tab);

    tab = actionBar.newTab()
            .setText("Sorteos Especiales")
            .setTabListener(new SorteosEspecialesFragment())
            .setIcon(R.drawable.sorteos_especiales);

    actionBar.addTab(tab);
```

Thank you everybody in advance

Comment: I still have no idea how to do this, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried the method "setCustomView" in the Tab class. You can create the layout you want and then add it to the tab. So lets say you create a layout with a ImageView and a TextView below it called "my_stacked_layout".

You can then do the following:

```
Tab tab = actionBar.newTab();
tab.setCustomView(R.layout.my_stacked_layout);
tab.setTabListener(new BotesSemanaFragment());
actionBar.addTab(tab);
```

Comment: That´s a good idea Marco but how can I manage the image and the text to show in each tab if it´s different? I have the LinearLayout with the ImageView and the TextView below it. Do I need a different xml for each tab? that´s the solution I find but for sure it can be made by code in the activity but I don´t know how to do it. Thanks Marco